# Update form from value change of Primefaces spinner

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to update my form on the basis of changes of the spinner

```
<p:spinner id="spin1" min="1" max="#{editPhoto.max}" size="1" 
           value="#{editPhoto.page}" validator="#{editPhoto.validator()}" 
           valueChangeListener="#{editPhoto.refreshForm()}" />
<p:commandButton value="Insert" action="#{editPhoto.insertImage()}"  />
<p:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{editPhoto.deleteImage()}" />
```

I've put break points in the value, setPage as well as in the validator and valueChangeListener and it hits them **only** when I press the commandButton. I've tried immediate="true", but that adds nothing. What I really want is to know when the value has been changed, but without having to hit the commandButton.

In a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869174/further-continuing-of-double-press) BalusC suggested the use of

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{nextpageBacking.onPreRenderView}" />
```

I suspect that I need something similar here, but what sort of event should I be looking for? Maybe not, so what do I need to do to get changes in the spinner without having to press on the commandButton? Thanks, Ilan

My bean is view-scoped. Perhaps the answer is to use another request scoped-bean and have the request scoped-bean operate on the view-scoped bean? I will try this if this looks like the correct direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `f:ajax` or `p:ajax`.

The valueChangeListener will only fire when the whole form or the spinner is submitted.

```
<p:spinner id="spin1" min="1" max="#{editPhoto.max}" size="1" 
           value="#{editPhoto.page}" validator="#{editPhoto.validator()}">
    <p:ajax listener="#{editPhoto.refreshForm()}" 
            update="@form" process="@this" />
</p:spinner>
```

The `valueChangeListener` attribute of the spinner is not the best place to fire your method. You should better put it in the `listener` attribute of `p:ajax`. The valueChangeListener should be used if you are interested in the old *and* the new value.

Comment: In addition, there are examples in the showcase of Primefaces, one is for Ajax Spinner : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/spinner.jsf

Comment: Absolutely beautiful. It is all so simple when you know the answer. I will remove the validator which existed just so I could catch a break point. Also I see you update the form which I what my bean refreshForm was supposed to do. Perhaps I don't even need the listener in this case. Thanks for the beautiful answer.

Comment: Notice that the `process` attribute is set to `@this` in my example and the spinner change will thus only reflect changes in the spinner itself. But you can change it to `@form` as well. Normally you don't need the listener function for only refreshing the form.

Comment: Great example... you really help me with this issue! Thanks