# Have to click JSF h:commandButton twice; ajax; the button is in ANOTHER view

Tags: ajax, jsf

my problem is similar to the next problems:

[have to press command button twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814888/have-to-press-command-button-twice)
and
http://balusc.blogspot.ru/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentWhichContainsAnotherForm

BUT

My **login button**(which I have to click twice) and the **ajax form** locates in different views (I've got the login view (the view with the login button) and the main view(where I use ajax to switch the one of the parts of this view)).

Here is the flow (how it happens):

When the session is expired and I try to make some ajax actions my AjaxExceptionHandler navigates me to the login view ("loginViewExpired") using this code:

```
facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(facesContext, null, "loginViewExpired");
facesContext.renderResponse();
```

And here I am, on my login view where I have to click the login button twice, because javax.faces.ViewState hidden input field is not added to my login form (as I understand from BalusC blog)

Any suggestions? Can I somehow transfer the ViewState to my form in login view from the ajax form in another view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using OmniFaces FullAjaxExceptionHandler

http://balusc.blogspot.ru/2012/03/full-ajax-exception-handler.html