# Have to click twice to go back to previous screen

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces, commandbutton

I am working in JSF very first time and without any knowledge in JSF. I did work on JavaScript, CSS, Ajax, Angular and Java. Since I don't know JSF, it is really difficult for me to understand why it is happening. And I do see there are some answers in Stack Overflow, but either they didn't work for or I could not understand.

Please help me here.

I have a search screen when I enter filter criteria/fields. Then I see results in the bottom of the same screen. Then I select any row and click on 'View Details' button, it takes me to another screen. In this detail screen, I have a 'Cancel' button.

Expectation:
On click (only once) of the 'Cancel' button, it should bring back me to the search screen.

Issue: On my first click on 'Cancel' button, it does nothing. On my second click, it takes back me to the search screen

I added a debug message in Java, On my first click on the Cancel button, it doesn't print that logger message. On my second click it prints.

Also I noticed on my first click, I see a POST call in Chrome browser Inspect -> Network tab

Here is my code:

JSF:

```xml
<h:form id="partQuoteCCRFormId" styleClass="mainForm" >
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="buttonGridStyle">
        <h:panelGroup>
            <p:commandButton value="Update Code" id="updatePartQuote" ajax="true"
                actionListener="#{partQuoteSearchBackingBean.displayDialog('UpdateQuoteCCR')}"
                update="costChangeReasonDlg,ccrDialogForm:costChangeReasonDD, ccrDialogForm:apply"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Cancel" id="cancelToSearch"
                action="#{partQuoteSearchBackingBean.performCancel('SearchScreen')}"
                ajax="true" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Java:

```java
public void performCancel(String targetPage){
    logger.debug("targetPage: " + targetPage);
    logger.info("targetPage: " + targetPage);
    
    try{
        if("SearchScreen".equals(targetPage)){
            //for setting focus by default
            //setFieldFocus("partQuoteSearchFormId:formPartQuoteSearchFocusID","partQuoteSearchFormId:partNumber");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("partQuoteSearch.xhtml");
        }else if("Home".equals(targetPage)){
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("index.xhtml");
        }
        else if("enterPartQuote".equals(targetPage)){
            //for setting focus
            setFieldFocus("enterPartQuoteFormId:formFocusID","enterPartQuoteFormId:partNumber");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("enterPartQuote.xhtml");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        handleSystemException(e, "messages");
    }       
}
```

Comment: Hello There - that doesn't answer my question. Please open it

Comment: The code is not in MCVE format and you haven't explicitly excluded at least the possible causes #2, #4, #5, #6, #11 in abovelinked dupe from being the cause in your actual case. Either post code in MCVE format ([instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)) or explicitly explain in your own words how you excluded these potential causes. In case you aren't understanding something then you should be more specific which part exactly you didn't understand instead of overgeneralizing it. You can always ask for clarification in a comment of the answer you found but didn't understood.